# Up to what extent can I use environment variables in Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I have a lot of jobs that contain very similiar configuration values.

Then I had the idea to use the [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to read a generated Properties file, which contains most of my configuration.

However, I don't know up to what extent I can use environment variables in a Jenkins job configuration.

For instance, in a Maven job, I can specify the Root POM to be `${JOB_NAME}/pom.xml`. Jenkins will tell me it can't find the file, but the job actually works.

Configuring other parts (like the number of builds to keep) fails miserably (the variable is simply removed).

So does anyone have experience in using environment variables to cut down the copy/paste configuration in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to cut down on cut and paste then the [job dsl plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) might suit your needs better.

You can build a template job ([using](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#using) statement) then use that to build your main jobs.

Modified from the [tutorial](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL)

```
job {
    name 'DSL-Tutorial-1-Test'
    using 'seed-job'
    scm {
        git('git://github.com/jgritman/aws-sdk-test.git')
    }
    triggers {
        scm('*/15 * * * *')
    }
    steps {
        maven('-e clean test')
    }
}
```

In addition if you need to change all the jobs you can change your template and rebuild the main jobs